# Psych can't parse simple key: value pair, Ruby, Yaml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, psych

Running in to some parsing problems with ruby 1.9.2-p290 and rails 3.1.3.

My YAML file looks like this:

```
api_key: 12345
```

The other YAML files parse fine, like the database.yml and locale files. It's just this one.
Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Can we see your entire YAML file which contains the field `api_key`?

Answer (score 0):

there must be an error somwhere else, cause the line that you are showing is parsable by psych and syck engines:

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'psych'
YAML.load("api_key: 12345") # => {"api_key"=>12345}
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
YAML.load("api_key: 12345") # => {"api_key"=>12345}
```